# Make not deleting intermediate files

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I know that Make's default behaviour is to delete intermediate files. I also added the `.INTERMEDIATE` special target to delete all intermediate `.o` files but Make is still not deleting them.

I've read all other posts with similar issues on Stackoverflow , followed what the answers suggested and nothing worked for me. Could someone please take a look? Here's my Make:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes
OBJS = server.o rio.o list.o
LDLIBS = -lpthread

.INTERMEDIATE: %.o

all: syst

sysstatd: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS) -o syst -L thread-pool -lthreadpool


server.o: server.h server.c
rio.o: rio.h rio.c
list.o: list.h list.c

clean:
     rm -f *~ *.o syst
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use

```
.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJS)
```

I don't believe you can use `%` syntax in `.INTERMEDIATE` targets, and `*.o` strikes me as far too risky. However, since you already have a convenient list of object files, why not just use it?